# Reinstallation of windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, installation

I'm debugging and extending a windows service I wrote about a month ago.
The following two scripts are my uninstall and install batch scripts I use.
The problem I'm facing is that when I install a new version and attach a debugger I cannot set breakpoints in the "new" code.

It seems as though either the service is cached somehow or the debugger cannot see that it's a new version.

things I've tried:
- delete current service files and replace them with new ones before uninstall/install
- completely killed the service (checked task manager too) and uninstalled it before deleting the files
- added some extra logging with does seem to to work (suggesting the new version is indeed installed), however other code located in another project used in the service is not executed (I think).
- set a new assembly version en reinstalled the service

EDIT:
- I deploy the entire bin/debug folder since it's a local test at the moment.

Any ideas why I can't seem to connect the debugger to the latest version?

batch scripts:
INSTALL

```
d:
cd D:\data\Import
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil HighCore.TaskList.ImportTaskResults.exe
net start ImportTaskResultService
PAUSE
```

UNINSTALL

```
d:
cd D:\data\Import
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil /u HighCore.TaskList.ImportTaskResults.exe
PAUSE
```

Comment: Have you deployed updated PDB files as well as .exe and dlls?

Comment: Yes I've deployed the entire bin/debug folder (since it's a local test at the moment). -> updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. An embarrassing one I'm afraid. I was building the project in release, but deploying it from the /bin/debug folder instead of from the /bin/release folder.